# Call to undefined function add_action() in plugin

Tags: plugins

I am creating a plugin but when I am trying to  print some data then I am getting this error so please do not mark this as a repeat question .

```
// Register Custom Post Type

function custom_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Post Types', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Post Type', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Post Types', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Item Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Post Type Description', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => false,
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'post_type', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );

function install(){
  custom_post_type() ; 
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'install');
if(!function_exists('get_event_data')){
function get_event_data(){
    $args= get_post(array(
         'post_type'   => 'post_type',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'fields' => 'ids'
    ));
    print_r($args);
}
}
add_action('init','get_event_data');
```

This code result is showing Call to undefined function `add_action()` error 
if I am trying to use other function like . `wp_head()` and `wp_enque_script()` still same error is coming.

Comment: Can you provide more context? E.g. what file is this in and how is it being called? I suspect this is a standalone PHP file being called directly but it's impossible tot ell with the limited information. Also `get_post` should be `get_posts`

Comment: The `add_action()` function is defined in WordPress core before plugins are loaded.

Comment: Where are you saving the plugin file? From the root path, what is the path to your plugin file?

Comment: Howdy_McGee@in root path

Comment: Tom J Nowell@you there??

Comment: Tom J Nowel@Tom Please see my updated question

Comment: @champtechnology are you calling this file directly? What is it's name and where is it located? You mention the root path but I don't know what you mean by that, is this in the same folder as `wp-admin` and `wp-includes`? Or do you mean `wp-content/plugins/`?

Comment: – Tom J Nowel@wp-content/plugins/